# value nonEmpty is not a member of Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda, types, anonymous-function

Below code works fine on Scala 2.11 and getting error "value nonEmpty is not a member of Object" on Scala 2.12. Can someone provide a solution?

```
val ds = spark.createDataset(List("abc","efg","xyz"))
ds.foreachPartition(
    partitionIterator =>
 {
        if(partitionIterator.nonEmpty){
            print(partitionIterator.getClass)
        }     
    }
)
```

Trying to migrate from Spark 2.4 to Spark 3.2 cluster and above code fails on Spark 3.2 cluster

Answer (score 2):

Try to add type of lambda parameter i.e. replace

```
ds.foreachPartition(
  partitionIterator => ...
```

with

```
ds.foreachPartition(
  (partitionIterator: Iterator[String]) => ...
```

The type is just not inferred in 2.12 on contrary to 2.11.

In Scala from time to time you have to specify types of variables, generics etc. although generally there is type inference.

When you switch from version to version, standard library changes, compiler type-inference algorithms change. Especially if you switch from 2.x to 2.y.

By the way, in 2.13 the error is `missing parameter type: partitionIterator => {` rather than `value nonEmpty is not a member of Object: if (partitionIterator.nonEmpty) {` in 2.12.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use the `hasNext` method instead of `nonEmpty`.

```
val ds = spark.createDataset(List("abc","efg","xyz"))
ds.foreachPartition(
  partitionIterator => {
    if(partitionIterator.hasNext) {
      print(partitionIterator.getClass)
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: `nonEmpty` is defined as `!isEmpty` and `isEmpty` as `!hasNext` https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.17/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L143 https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.17/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L387

Comment: I mean you're saving an extra method call but this can't fix compilation